# Should I use the ATI proprietary or free drivers with two Crossfire HD5850s?

Tags: drivers, ati, open-source

I own 2 XFX Radeon HD 5850 in crossfire configuration connected to 3 24" monitors.

I really want to make Ubuntu my daily OS but can't seem to find the best configuration to use.

Some threads say that the free driver is better then the ATI one and some say the new Catalyst fully takes advantage of the card capabilities.

Anyone out there with a similar setup? What are your recommendations for a good production in 12.04 setup?

Answer (score 1):

Proprietary ATI drivers usually gives better performance and lower power consumption, but also can cause some minor graphic glitches due to some incompatibilities. But I have no experience with using multiple monitors so I can't say which one is better for this purpose.

Comment: I've noticed things with catalyst in the past in multi-monitor configurations where my cursor would be pretty bad looking (corrupt if you will), a bit of a pain but not the end of the world.

3D performance is miles ahead of the open drivers, but 2D support is very good with the open drivers. Figuring they're fairly fancy cards I'd say Catalyst would be the most suiting.